# Regex Pattern validation in Java to match 2 decimal points

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, decimal-point

I need to validate a number pattern with 2 decimal points with after each decimal point it can contain only up to 2 digits. It can contain a whole number only up to 4 digits.

Ex: maximum value it can insert is in this format `yyyy.yy.yy`

```
 yyyy - allow without any decimal places
   yyyy.y - allow
   yyyy.y.y - allow
```

`yyyy.yyy.yy` - can't allow (Since this has 3 digits after 1 decimal point)
`yyyy.yy.yyy` - can't allow (Since this has 3 digits after 2 decimal point)

```
yyyy.y.yy  - (Allow)
yyyy.yy.y  - (Allow)
```

**yyyy**.yy.y  - (Allow)

bold part only allow up to 4 digits.

Currently if i use this validation `^[0-9]{1,4}(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`
This validation works for this correctly.

```
yyyy.yy - maximum value
```

But I want to validate this `yyyy.yy.yy`.If i use `^[0-9]{1,4}(\\.[0-9]{0,2})(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`
for this `yyyy.yy.yy` It doesn't work properly.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match here?

Comment: i want to match this format yyyy.yy.yy     yyyy- (can have numbers up to 4 digits. minimum 1 number) .yy (can have numbers up to 2 digits.)

Comment: yyyy - value also should be able to insert without any decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex contains duplication. You can add quantifier to second group. Try this regex

```
^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2}){0,2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVjxti/1)

Java example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[] {"1234", "1234.1.2", "1234.22.22", "1234.2", "1.2.3", // all match
                                 "5.555.5", "55555", "5.55.555"}; // all don't match

    for(String s : arr) {
        if(s.matches("^\\d{1,4}(\\.\\d{0,2}){0,2}$")) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1234
1234.1.2
1234.22.22
1234.2
1.2.3
```